# Pre-creating tags [crypto++] and [cryptopp] for email notifications

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

I have subject matter expertise in the [Crypto++ library](http://www.cryptopp.com/). I'd like to set up email notifications for the library.

I noticed the site does not have tags for the library. Is it OK to set up tags in advance for email notifications?

(Related, there may be [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972135/encryption-using-many-algorthims-within-crypto) arriving from Stack Overflow.)

---

In case this should be a feature request, here are the specs:

- Tag: [crypto++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto%2b%2b)
- Synonym: [cryptopp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptopp)

The library's proper name is Crypto++, hence the [crypto++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto%2b%2b) tag. But many distributions provide a name of [cryptopp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptopp) (perhaps for file system friendliness), so questions sometimes have that tag too. We use the same on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If/when the question is migrated, it will come over with whatever tags are here already. We can look at the individual tagging after it arrives.

The SE system does not support 'creating' tags unless you create them on an existing post... the post comes first. So, let's cross that bridge when it arrives...

**Update:**

The question this relates to [was cross-posted to CR already](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63566/31503). I added a new [crypto++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto%2b%2b) tag to the post, and it can now be subscribed to. If [cryptopp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptopp) is used in the future, we can sym-link them.

Comment: Hmmm.... this question was already asked here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63566/encryption-with-many-algorithms-using-crypto

Comment: Thanks rofl. I guess that means there's no way to set up a notification?

Comment: @jww - please join us in chat - [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: @jww - I have created the tag on the existing question - you are now able to subscribe to it as well. If the need arises, in the future, and someone 'accidentally' creates the cryptopp tag, we can create the synonym then.

Comment: @Rofl - sorry for the delay. Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't transporting bridges quite difficult? :-)