# Current synonymization of [crypto++]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

[Crypto++ is a C++ cryptographic library](http://www.cryptopp.com/). CR used to have a dedicated tag for it: [crypto++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto%2b%2b). Related, see [Pre-create tags 'crypto++' and 'cryptopp' for email notifications?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2511).

I have an alert that triggers whenever someone uses the tag. The issue is, the tag is now a synonym for [cryptography](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography), so I get mostly spurious hits.

What should be done? Should the site undo the synonym? Or should I remove the notification?

Comment: Please explain the down vote. Something that used to work is now broken, and I am trying to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Downvotes on meta are a bit difficult to interpret: maybe your post was unclear, maybe the voter thinks the issue is not worth discussing, maybe the voter disagrees with the proposal. In any case, it doesn't affect your reputation score or your self-worth.

Comment: @200_success - it was clearly tagged with support. Its ***not*** an agree/disagree question. Educate your users.

Comment: There is still an underlying request here (removing the synonym), so that could be the source of the disagreement.  Users may not factor the tags into this.

Comment: @Jamal - that's fine. That's not a battle worth fighting to me. CR.SE can do what it wants. I just needed to know how to proceed, and you answered that for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Now related: [Subscribe to tagged questions on all sites except one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260457)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I primarily performed the synonymization because [crypto++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto%2b%2b) seemed more of a "low-traffic" tag while burnination didn't quite seem appropriate.  This may not have been a good move anyway, but I'll let the community decide on it.

Other than that, yes, you can always remove the notification if you'd like.

Comment: OK, thanks. Let me know if it becomes a stand alone tag again and I'll be happy to subscribe and answer questions.

Comment: Using synonymization as a tool to effectively retag questions with [tag:crypto++] to [tag:cryptography] is fine (assuming that the questions already had [tag:c++], and that [tag:crypto++] is really not desired here). But after that, don't leave [tag:crypto++] as a synonym of [tag:cryptography], the two terms aren't anything like synonyms.

Comment: I don't see how removing the tag [tag:crypto++] is useful. A question about code using crypto++ should probably be tagged [tag:cryptography], but if the focus is on something other than the crypto such as memory management, it would make sense to tag a question [tag:c++] [tag:memory-management] [tag:crypto++] and not [tag:cryptography].

Comment: @Giles - also see [Subscribe to tagged questions on all sites except one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260457/173448). The decision appears be problematic due to interactions with the notification system.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow has specific tags for individual libraries because users are interested in solving problems using a particular library.

Code Review, on the other hand, is more interested in finding the best approach for accomplishing a task. An answer might even advise you to use a better library altogether.  Therefore, we tend to create tags for frameworks and very popular libraries.  A question about Crypto++ is probably adequately covered by the [cryptography](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) tag.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Stack Overflow. This question is about locating and answering questions for the Crypto++ library.

Comment: Code Review has specific tags for individual libraries.  Code Reviewers are interested in solving problems using particular libraries.